# Why do I get IP from romania even though I am located in germany?

Tags: networking, vpn

I tried to chat on a certain site, but it said it is not allowed, since I am behind a VPN. So I [looked up my IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/) and It mentions CYBERGHOST and that my provider is Telekom Romania

```
inetnum:        85.9.20.128 - 85.9.20.255
netname:        CYBERGHOST
descr:          Cyberghost
country:        RO
admin-c:        GTRO1-RIPE
tech-c:         GTRO1-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         AS5606-MNT
created:        2014-11-03T12:31:33Z
last-modified:  2014-11-03T12:31:33Z
source:         RIPE

role:           GTS Telecom Romania Operations
address:        GTS Telecom Romania
address:        92-96 Izvor St.
address:        050564 Bucharest
address:        ROMANIA
phone:          +40 31 220 0455
fax-no:         +40 31 220 0222
abuse-mailbox:  abuse@gtstelecom.ro
admin-c:        ANDY14
admin-c:        RCB
tech-c:         ANDY14
tech-c:         RCB
nic-hdl:        GTRO1-RIPE
mnt-by:         AS5606-MNT
created:        2004-10-07T07:37:34Z
last-modified:  2019-02-15T09:33:46Z
source:         RIPE # Filtered

% Information related to '85.9.0.0/18AS5588'

route:          85.9.0.0/18
descr:          GTS Telecom
descr:          Member of GTS Central Europe
descr:          Bucharest / ROMANIA
origin:         AS5588
mnt-by:         GTSCE-MNT
created:        2013-09-11T06:56:55Z
last-modified:  2013-09-11T06:56:55Z
source:         RIPE

% Information related to '85.9.0.0/18AS5606'

route:          85.9.0.0/18
descr:          GTS Telecom
descr:          Member of GTS Central Europe
descr:          Bucharest / ROMANIA
origin:         AS5606
mnt-by:         AS5606-MNT
created:        2005-02-11T08:57:48Z
last-modified:  2005-02-11T08:57:48Z
source:         RIPE

% This query was served by the RIPE Database Query Service version 1.96 (HEREFORD)
```

But cyberghost does not even run. I was connected to Cyberghost Romania, yesterday. How is this possible? I also checked in task manager.

```
tracert www.stackoverflow.com

Routenverfolgung zu stackoverflow.com [151.101.129.69]
über maximal 30 Hops:

  1    35 ms    35 ms    35 ms  10.247.200.1
  2    35 ms    35 ms    35 ms  85.9.20.129
  3    65 ms    66 ms    65 ms  10.49.19.1
  4    65 ms    67 ms    67 ms  193.85.195.49
  5    65 ms    65 ms    65 ms  ae-2.fra2027-ex1.gtsce.net [193.85.195.94]
  6    73 ms    73 ms    74 ms  195.122.181.221
  7    73 ms    74 ms    73 ms  ae-2-3207.edge5.Frankfurt1.Level3.net [4.69.163.22]
  8    65 ms    65 ms    65 ms  212.162.24.214
  9    66 ms    65 ms    66 ms  151.101.129.69

Ablaufverfolgung beendet.
```

**UPDATE:** I restarted my computer, now I got a german IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first IP in the chain is indeed in Romania, city of Bucharest,
according to the
[IP Location Finder](https://www.iplocation.net/).

The conclusion is that CyberGhost is still running.

Comment: But the task was not running. I figured out that there is also a cyberghost service which was running, I believe it is because of that service. I think I put my computer in energy saving mode while it was connected to the VPN.

Comment: CyberGhost may indeed have two components, service and client interface, as proven when you rebooted. You should have used the client interface part to turn it off before killing it, if you really wanted it so. Evidently, you have not set CyberGhost to run on boot, so the reboot reset everything to its proper state.

Answer (score 0):

A VPN is just that: a *Virtual Private network*, with your details hidden behind the VPN provider's walls.

Most VPN's give you choices for the server used. See the screenshot below, for example; each triangle represents the location of a ProtonVPN server. If you don't like the location automatically selected, pick another. As technical support staff often state, *Read The Fine Manual*, RTFM.

[image: VPN GUI]

Comment: Thats obvious, but the cyberghost task was not running. But I think it was the cyberghost service.